# Extract a struct member from an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, struct, boost-bind

I have an array of structures that contain multiple variables:

```
struct test_case {
    const int input1;
    //...
    const int output;
};

test_case tc[] = {
    {0,  /**/  1},
    //  ...
    {99, /**/ 17}
};

int tc_size = sizeof(tc) / sizeof(*tc);
```

and I want to extract a vector of the `output`s so I can compare them to another array via `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS`.

I came up with this:

```
struct extract_output {
    int operator()(test_t &t) {  
        return t.output;  
    }
}

std::vector<int> output_vector;

std::transform(test_cases, 
               test_cases + tc_size, 
               back_inserter(output_vector), 
               extract_output());
```

but it seems like I should be able to do this without a functor/struct for each type.

Is there a quicker way to extract a vector/array of one variable from a struct?  I tried using boost::lambda, but this didn't work:

```
std::transform(test_cases, 
               test_cases + tc_size, 
               back_inserter(output_vector), 
               _1.output);
```

Apparently [`operator.()` cannot be used on lambda variables](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#id1341629)...  what should I use?  boost::bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, adding boost::bind is the answer:

```
std::transform(test_cases, 
               test_cases + tc_size, 
               back_inserter(output_vector), 
               boost::bind(&test_case::output, _1));
```

This works because `std::transform` passes in a `test_case` parameter into the functor generated by `bind()`.  The functor applies the [member pointer syntax `(&T::x)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers) to extract and return the member variable.